# Skip certain folders containing static content during GoConvey testing of endpoint REST API

Tags: go, goconvey

I have a `public` folder to serve static resources. I wrote tests to save static content in this folder using Convey.

It gets stuck in a never-ending loop due to the new files created in the public folder.

`integration.go:120: File system state modified, publishing current folders... 1452848214 1452848215`

How can I skip this folder? I tried adding `.goconvey` file to the folder with `ignore` but its not working.

Any suggestions, how to skip watching that folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag in GoConvey which helps in skipping those folders.

`goconvey -excludedDirs="public"`

https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/blob/master/goconvey.go#L44

Source: https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/issues/383